# Suggest module for maintaining inventory and image zoom drupal commerce

Tags: drupal-7, overlay, inventory, drupal-commerce

I have created a website using drupal 7 commerce now I need a module for two functionality

1.) To manage inventory for the website so that the user can only by the item that are available in my inventory.

2.) I want to add a image hover effect plus the overlay effect on the product page so that the users will able to zoom in to the product.

please suggest the suitable modules or do i need to write my own module for this,

Answer (score 1):

For inventory management try [Commerce Stock](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock) a contrib module.

If you want an out of the box experience you can try [Commerce Kickstart Installation Profile](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). If you choose to install demo store which is optional while installing Commerce KS, you can view a demo of an example zoom into the product functions. As zooming function is independent of drupal commerce you can use any module like [Cloud Zoom](http://drupal.org/project/cloud_zoom) to achieve the desired effect.